# Struts2 submit button bind to enter

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts2

I have a .jsp page which also uses struts2.  This page has two buttons on it.  A submit, and a reset button.  I wish the enter key to be bound to the submit button.  Any advice on how to do this?  I am a Struts2/JSP novice.  the screen is a simple login screen.

```
<s:form action="postLogin" onSubmit="return validate()">                        
   <div style="padding-left:50px">
        <s:submit type="button" value="Submit" cssClass="buttonRounded" name="submitButton" label="%{getText('prompt.button.submit')}"/>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button value="Reset"  class="buttonRounded" onclick="resetPage()">Reset</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I am not using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
shortcut.add("Enter",function() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
});
```

> Name your form myForm.